# IntelliJ Editor "Cannot resolve symbol" but still compiles and runs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

IntelliJ version 2016.3

I have a Gradle project that I import into an IntelliJ project. Some of the test classes show, in the editor, that a class they use from an external library can't be found.

This library seems to get imported just fine by Gradle, and when I run the test in IntelliJ it compiles and runs just fine.

I have tried invalidating caches and restarting, refreshing Gradle, and deleting the IntelliJ configuration directories.

Why would IntelliJ's editor show a class as "not found" when its compiler says otherwise?